# Cannot find debian mirror while installing Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to install Raspbian using the Raspbian Installer (i.e. not an image). But When I'm stuck when I've to to choose a Debian archive. [image: screenshot]

I always get an errors like `Mirror does not support the specified release` or `Mirror does not have any suit symlinks`.

I can use `wget` to retrieve content on the web. So, I have internet connection. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you positive you're connected to the internet?

Comment: You're trying to add Debian mirror to Raspian sources. You can't do that. Please follow Jens Peter Nielsen's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
      deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: This is rather old - anybody reading this later on will want to change "wheezy" to "jessie" now or probably some other Toy-story character in the future but NOT "sid" (as that is always the **unstable development Debian version** from which Raspbian is derived).

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever need to choose a Debian archive. Raspbian has it hard-coded. If you've changed it, change it back to Jens Peter Nielsen's example.