# Raspbian installation fails: Bad archive mirror

Tags: raspbian, debian

I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller) on installing a fresh installation of Raspbian. I get as far as 'Choose a mirror of the Debian archive' but I am then greeted with the error 'Bad archive mirror' when trying to retrieve the mirror ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBUpv.png) from another [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/cannot-find-debian-mirror-while-install-raspbian)). However, as far as I can see there are no errors, and as far as I know the network is configured correctly.

If the network isn't configured correctly what would be the best way to test for this?

Completely new to this sort of thing so apologies if above doesn't make sense

Comment: Why not use the official Foundation image which is up to date. AFAIK the Raspbian site no longer offers images.

Comment: Images are not reliable too. They can easily get corrupt

Comment: Not only can they become outdated or corrupt, but as recently happened they can be the source of malware.

Comment: Only official images should be used as they are near guaranteed to work when correctly installed. They also will not cause any damage to the Pi and will allow you to use the Pi to its full potential.

Comment: Some people trust a self-built images more than a downloaded one "from the internet".